# Firebase functions Storage file download link generation is taking time

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am generating a signed url after uploading a file from firebase functions but it is taking time upto 5 seconds. My main work completes in 5 seconds but the link generation is adding more waiting to user.

This is function i used:

```
function getSignedUrl(file) {
    console.time('URLGenerated ');
    /**
     * Handle url generation url to properly handle user veiws
     * Crete catch error to see if it is logged properly
     */
    let options = { action: 'read', expires: Date.now() + 5 * 60 * 1000 }; // 5min Expiration Time
    let bucketFileName = path.join(crypto.randomBytes(12).toString('hex'), path.basename(file));

    return bucket.upload(file, { destination: `public/${bucketFileName}` })
        .then(() => {
            return bucket.file(`public/${bucketFileName}`).getSignedUrl(options)
                .then((urls) => {
                    fs.unlinkSync(file);
                    console.timeEnd('URLGenerated ');
                    return urls[0];
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    console.log('Link Generation Error' + e);
                });
        }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

file size is arond 200 - 350 KB.

the last generation took 3.5 seconds that's crucial.

What's going on ? how to reduce the time ?

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be slowed down by `fs.unlinkSync` method which is synchronous. So the code is waiting for file removal (references [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-unlinksync-method/) and [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback)).

According to my understanding removing of uploaded file is not crucial for link generation and so out of the function purpose. Question is if it's worth to wait for it and I think that this operation (file removing) could be done outside the function `getSignedUrl`, invoked after the link is provided.

I would try with testing with removed `fs.unlinkSync` and check if there what is execution time.

You can use as well asynchronous version of the function [unlink](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback), but I think that more clear will be to do it outside.

Comment: No luck. still getting 3-5 seconds of time. removed file removal completely. Still same. If i use emulator then the time is hardly 1.5 seconds but when i deploy it to cloud the time increases. Why is that.I provisioned 2GB of ram but still no luck..

Comment: How often did you run the function?